# Is there a tomcat 64 bit version

Tags: java, 64bit

Is there a tomcat 64 bit version for Linux, I am using Red Hat Linux?.

Comment: What matters is the JVM. So just run tomcat on a 64 bit JVM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes no sense.

Just install the 64bit version of [JRE/JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and every Java software you download and run will just utilize the 64bit features whenever applicable.

In contrary to C# and like, Java is designed to be platform independent. Whatever Java code you write, it'll run on both 32bit and 64bit machines. It's a matter of the right JVM.

Comment: Tomcat has a native code accelleration module for better performance.  It is not required, though.

Comment: Of course, there's something of a rift between "Designed to be" and "actually is"...